# Read a .csv file and join values based on equal values in specific column

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a csv file which has three columns (A, B, and C) and their values are like the below figure:
[CSV Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isvMl.png)

```
1,2,4
1,257,5
1,258,6
1,8,7
1,260,8
2,24,9
2,26,10
2,234,11
3,14,12
3,22,13
3,78,14
```

I want to join the values in column B by **"-"** while their values in column A are the same. So, the expected outputs are as below:

**["2-257-258-8-260", "24-26-234", "14-22-78"]**

Can anyone help me how can I get these results.

Thanks in advance

Comment: post a testable input fragment, don't post input as images

Comment: It would make it easier for people to help you if you included that sample data as text in your question. It's not so easy copying data from an image. Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). You should also post your own attempt at writing code for this task, explaining clearly where you're having difficulties.

Comment: Your output doesn't imply any logic of what you are describing

Comment: I understand what you want to do, but will the values in column A always be grouped together? And will they always be sorted in ascending order?

Comment: @Mohammad Please try my answer

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, they always grouped together. For the second part of your question, not necessarily. In fact, in my real data, the column "A" are unsorted and the sort function is needed.

Comment: @U8-Forward Thanks, I got the answer with the pandas package as well.

Comment: @Mohammad Does my answer work for you?, if it does work, please accept my answer

Comment: My solution works on unsorted data, and since it sorts the keys the output will be in the correct order but of course the order of the items in each output string will reflect the original order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a plain Python solution.

We use a `csv` reader to read the data. In my code I read from a list of lines named `file_data`, but you can change `file_data` to an open file object.

We store the data into a dictionary of lists, with the column A value as the key, and the column B values being appended to a list.

We then loop over the keys in order, joining the B data into strings of the desired form.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

file_data = '''\
1,2,4
1,257,5
1,258,6
1,8,7
1,260,8
2,24,9
2,26,10
2,234,11
3,14,12
3,22,13
3,78,14
'''.splitlines()

reader = csv.reader(file_data)
data = defaultdict(list)
for a, b, c in reader:
    #print(a, b, c)
    data[a].append(b)

out = ['-'.join(data[k]) for k in sorted(data.keys())]
print(out)
```

**output**

```
['2-257-258-8-260', '24-26-234', '14-22-78']
```

Comment: Thanks for all answers, but this code gave me thr best time performce for a large dataset among the other answers, thanks dude:)

Answer (score 2):

If your dataset is in the format:

```
A,B,C
1,2,4
1,257,5
1,258,6
1,8,7
1,260,8
2,24,9
2,26,10
2,234,11
3,14,12
3,22,13
3,78,14
```

You could use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group items from the `A` column, and join the elements from the `B` column:

```
from csv import reader
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

with open('data.csv') as in_file:
    csv_reader = reader(in_file)

    # skip headers
    next(csv_reader)

    # sort data by A column, then C column
    sorted_data = sorted(csv_reader, key=itemgetter(0, 2))

    # group by A column, and join by B column
    grouped = ['-'.join(map(itemgetter(1), g)) for _, g in groupby(sorted_data, key=itemgetter(0))]
    print(grouped)
```

Which Outputs:

```
['2-257-258-8-260', '24-26-234', '14-22-78']
```

**Note:** This solution sorts before it groups, just in case the data is not already sorted primarily on column `A`, then secondarily on column `C`.

Comment: FWIW, I also thought of using `groupby`, but I didn't want to have to sort the data, and the OP hasn't replied to my question about it always being sorted. BTW, nice use of `itemgetter`. I hate it when people use `map` on a `lambda`.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yeah I assumed it wouldn't be a problem sort beforehand. Of course this solution would still work if the data is always sorted, it was just a safety measure. I presonally prefer your `defaultdict` method though.

Comment: BTW, you could make the sorting key function `itemgetter(0, 2)` so that items are sorted on column A as the primary key and column C as a secondary key.

Answer (score 1):

## Pandas solution

Try using the pandas [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/groupby.html) function then use the pandas [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) then write `lambda x:` in it then, join the new list comprehension with `'-'`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3], 'B': [124,456,465,46,35,53,33]})
print(df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: '-'.join([str(i) for i in x.values])).tolist())
```

Output:

```
['124-456-465', '46-35', '53-33']
```

Comment: What makes you think the OP has Pandas? This task can easily be done using the standard `csv` module and a `defaultdict`, or even a plain `dict`.